# Add one more value to csv from text file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, text, converters

I am converting multiple text files to a csv file. My text file looks like this:

```
ITEM: TIMESTEP
55000
ITEM: NUMBER OF ATOMS
4365
ITEM: BOX BOUNDS ff ff ff
-0.3 0.3
-0.6 0.6
-0.6 0.6
ITEM: ATOMS id type x y z vx vy vz fx fy fz omegax omegay omegaz radius 
4356 1 -0.0885288 -0.0101421 -0.48871 -0.000941682 0.778688 -0.0153902 -0.00720861 -0.0533703 0.0104717 0.35581 -0.0601358 -0.436049 0.01 
4227 1 0.0157977 0.00542603 -0.488429 -0.00996111 0.784119 0.00813807 -0.000491847 0.0144889 -0.0120111 1.08208 -0.0671177 0.369492 0.01 
3973 1 0.0179724 0.0256167 -0.48799 -0.00582994 0.772455 0.0394544 0.0109589 -0.0187232 -0.00111718 -0.0586513 -0.162943 1.12784 0.01 
4300 1 0.0900919 0.0248592 -0.488025 -0.000455483 0.769978 0.0388239 -0.00364509 0.0409803 -0.00269227 3.94355 -0.0249566 -0.223111 0.01 
4200 1 -0.0230223 0.0329911 -0.483108 -0.00238 0.778547 0.0500186 0.0421189 -0.021588 0.05607 0.112989 -0.0813771 -1.09981 0.015 
4339 1 0.00143577 0.0368542 -0.488107 0.000587848 0.784672 0.0593572 0.00385562 -0.00475113 -0.00710483 -0.201196 0.158512 -5.63826 0.01 
4106 1 0.0648392 0.0269728 -0.483248 -0.00365836 0.766081 0.0395827 0.0418642 0.1802 0.0547313 -0.0578358 0.124205 -0.96464 0.015 
4104 1 -0.084453 0.0507114 -0.482726 -0.000596577 0.75636 0.0806599 0.000817826 0.0119286 -0.0150014 -0.0864852 -0.103877 0.198773 0.015
```

Right now my csv file contains value after line 9 (in python code line 8).
I want to include line 2 (Header - TIMESTEP) also in csv along with all the values after 9.

I tried to edit my code but couldn't succeed. Can I get some help:
My code is here:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv
import glob
import time


def main():
    start = time.time()
    data_folder = "./all/" #folder name
    files = glob.glob(data_folder + '*dump*.data')
    print("Total files:", len(files))
    # get header from one of the files
    #header = []
    with open('all/dump46000.data', 'r') as f:
        #lines = f.readlines()
        for _ in range(8):
            next(f) # skip first 8 lines
        header = ','.join(f.readline().split()[2:]) + '\n'
        headers = ','.join(f.readline().split()[2:])
        #header.append(headers)
        #header.append('timestep')
        print(header)
    for file in files:
        with open(file, 'r') as f, open(f'all.csv', 'a') as g: # note the 'a'
            g.write(header) # write the header
            for _ in range(9):
                next(f) # skip first 9 lines
            for line in f:
                g.write(line.rstrip().replace(' ', ',') + '\n')
    print(time.time() - start)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My folder `all` contains more than 600 files:

```
['./all/dump501000.data', 
'./all/dump307000.data',
'./all/dump612000.data',
'./all/dump369000.data',
'./all/dump23000.data',
'./all/dump470000.data',
'./all/dump235000.data',
'./all/dump6000.data',
'./all/dump568000.data',
'./all/dump506000.data',
'./all/dump623000.data',
'./all/dump329000.data',
'./all/dump220000.data', 
.....................
....................
```

I want this csv file from text file:

```
id type x y z vx vy vz fx fy fz omegax omegay omegaz radius TIMESTEP
```

But I am getting this csv

```
id type x y z vx vy vz fx fy fz omegax omegay omegaz radius
```

Thank you

Comment: Could you print a tree file for your directory as well?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve what you want, based on the TXT file in the question what would the perfect csv look like?

Comment: Your question is framed wrong, thanks for the answer I think I better understand what you want. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enter code here`Here is something you can try to add TIMESTEP with your data in csv. I am just wondering if you need to print the header for each file. My understanding is you can print header at the top for once. If you want to print that for each file, bring it into the for loop.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv
import glob
import time


def main():
    start = time.time()
    data_folder = "./all/" #folder name
    files = glob.glob(data_folder + '*dump*.data')
    print("Total files:", len(files))
    # get header from one of the files
    header = []

    with open('all/dump46000.data', 'r') as f:
        #lines = f.readlines()
        header.extend(f.readline().split()[1:]) 
        timeStep = f.readline().split()
        
        for _ in range(6):
            next(f) # skip first 8 lines
        header.extend(f.readline().split()[2:]) 
        a = True
        print(header)
        headerString = ','.join(header)
        

    for file in files:
        with open(file, 'r') as f, open(f'all.csv', 'a') as g: # note the 'a'
            next(f)
            g.write(headerString+ '\n') # write the header
            timeStep = f.readline().split()
            for _ in range(7):
                next(f)
            for line in f:
                file_line = line.split()
                file_line.insert(0,timeStep[0])
                data = ','.join(file_line)
                g.write(data + '\n')

    print(time.time() - start)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: It's giving me an error. `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'g' referenced before assignment'

Comment: May be you missed to copy the whole while line `with open(file, 'r') as f, open(f'all.csv', 'a') as g: # note the 'a'`

Comment: I think, i copied everything.Still throws same error. Is it working in your system?

Comment: Sorry I figured out, it was indention. Yes it is working at my side. I have edited the code. Please try again now.

Comment: Still, same error. If I edit and uncomment line 27, it gives me csv without TIMESTEP column.

Comment: Sorry again. Accidentally moved the `g.write(headerString+ '\n') # write the header` out of `with open(file`. Please try now one more time with fixed code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244273/discussion-between-im-vutu-and-codeholic).

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you want, here's what should work

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv
import glob
import time


def main():
    start = time.perf_counter()
    data_folder = "./all/" #folder name
    files = glob.glob(data_folder + '*dump*.data')
    print("Total files:", len(files))
    for file in files:
        with open(file, 'r') as f, open(f'all.csv', 'a') as g: # note the 'a'
            header = f.readline().split("ITEM: ")[1] + '\n'
            headers = f.readline()
            print(header)
            g.write(header)
            g.write(headers)
            for _ in range(6):
                next(f)
            for line in f:
                g.write(line.rstrip().replace(' ', ',') + '\n')
    print(time.perf_counter() - start)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Let me know if you need any other syntax or something else in the final CSV.
Also to time something always use time.perf_counter it's more accurate.

Comment: This gives me the csv like previous one. It doesn't include the TIMESTEP column.